# how to use push notification for send notification from one user to another user. Using Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 - Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud, messaging

i want to show notification for if one user pay successfully payment then it should send notification to corresponding user. i want to use legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 - Firebase

anyone know please tell me!